# How to retrieve visible text alone from webelement?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation

How to get only the text that is visible (excluding hidden texts) on UI from a webelement (Selenium) using java? I have tried using javascript. For example:

```
<span class='message'>
this part is visible
<span>
visible
</pan>
<span>
hidden
</span>
visible
</span>
```

I wan to retrieve only "this part is visible visible visible" from span with class 'message'.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: You probably should add some more details... some code you have tried and a relevant HTML example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code is working for me.

```
public String getVisibleTextFromElement(WebElement elem)
{
    String visibleText= (String) getJavaScriptExecutor().executeScript("var clone = $(arguments[0]).clone();"
            + "clone.appendTo('body').find(':hidden').remove();"
            + "var text = clone.text();"
            + "clone.remove(); return text;", elem);
    visibleText=visibleText.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    return visibleText;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`getElementText` chapter of the latest WebDriver specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#getelementtext), if you would just get the text of an element, selenium would only return you the visible text:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myid")).getText();
```